# Role a 6 to win! PHP Code

Tags: php

I'm currently learning how to use do/while loops in PHP through codeacademy.  I'm working on a challenge where you create a six-sided die and continue rolling until you get a six.  Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
<?php
$roll = 1;

do {
echo “Roll Number " . $roll . ".  Begin rolling for a 6.";
} while ($roll != 6); {
for ($rollNumber = 1; $roll != 6; $roll ++) {
$roll = rand(1, 6);
echo "On roll number " . $rollNumber .  "You got  a " $roll ".\n";
};}
?>
```

I though the best way to get started is by creating a roll variable that we can use once for the do loop to check if it's working:

```
$roll = 1;
```

I set the value to one instead of zero, because there's no zero number on a die, and we'll assume the player first rolls a one.  Next I want to check if the do loop is working so I echo the following:

```
do {
echo “Roll Number " . $roll . ".  Begin rolling for a 6.";
}
```

After making sure the do loop worked, I create the while condition:

```
while ($roll != 6) {
```

Then I want to create a rollNumber variable to keep track of what roll I'm on and increment it:

```
for ($rollNumber = 1; $roll != 6; $roll ++) {
```

next I set the value of the roll variable so that it generates a random number between 1 and 6:

```
$roll = rand(1,6);
```

Finally I want to echo the message "On roll number  you got a ." :

```
echo “On roll number “ . $rollNumber .  "You got  a " $roll “.\n";}
```

For some reason the code's not working.  Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with a `while` loop and `rand()`. The only other thing you needed was to set a count variable to display the roll number (you can just increment this variable on every "roll").

Your code could be simplified to this:

```
$c = $n = 1;
while ($n != 6) {
  echo 'on roll number ' . $c++ . ' you rolled a ' . $n = rand(1, 6) . "\n";
}
```

#### [Here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/blaI2E)

Comment: This was the simplest example.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've made this way too complicated. There's no need for two loops.

```
$rolled = 0;
$numbers = range(1, 6); //generate array with 1-6
$counter = 0;
while($rolled!=6)
{
    $counter++;
    shuffle($numbers); //shuffle array
    $rolled = $numbers[0]; //grab first item
    echo '<br/>(Roll ' . $counter . ') ' . $rolled;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense as well.  I hadn't thought of using an array.  I wasn't aware of the shuffle method either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a function that returns the result of a roll, and then a loop that calls this function until it returns a 6?

```php
<?php

function roll() {
    return mt_rand(1, 6);
}

$roll = 1;

do {
    if (roll() == 6) {
        printf('You rolled a 6 on roll %d.', $roll);
        break;
    }
    $roll++;
} while (0);
```

This `do`/`while` loop continues until the `roll()` function returns a 6.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  The class hasn't dived into functions yet, but I assume they follow the same structure as JavaScript.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure where JavaScript comes into this? Also, this isn’t a class. It’s a procedural PHP script.